# LWC @wire can not get apex return value

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire

I'm not getting the success string below

Apex

```java
 @AuraEnabled
 public static string methodName(){
     return 'success';
 }
```

LWC JS

```js
 @wire(methodName) 
 returnstr(result){
     console.log('xxx = ' + result.data);
 }
```

[image: Console]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please edit your post to provide the code as text. You should also find out the value of “error”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) for apex method whenever you are using @wire.